# Dialog box not displaying upon clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dialog

I have a site which has the button 'Currency Converter'. When clicked on it, it should open the dialog box and conversion should happen. Following is the code:

**currency_converter.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#openwindow').each(function() {
                    var $link = $(this);
                    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                        .load($link.attr('href'))
                        .dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            title: $link.attr('title'),
                            width: 500,
                            height: 300
                        });
    
                    $link.click(function() {
                        $dialog.dialog('open');
    
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
    
                $('#wrapper').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Basic Dialog'
                });
                $('#opener').click(function() {
                    var page = "https://www.google.com/finance/converter";
    
                    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                        .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                        .dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            height: 250,
                            width: 350,
                            title: "Currency Converter"
                        });
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                    return false;   
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <button id="opener">Currency Converter</button>
    <div id="wrapper">
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**The problem is: dialog box is not getting opened in my browser.**

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: It works just fine for me too. Try checking if you have JavaScript enabled in your browser or try in incognito mode.

Comment: Yes, but its not working in my browser

Comment: Let me check the settings then

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: what is your browser?  Move alll the client code inside of a single $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Its not working in all browsers in my PC and hosting account is Godaddy. URL is: https://www.friendbazar.com/currency_converter.php

Comment: Is it because SSL is installed for the site?

Comment: I used https for external scripts used in the code and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chnage your jquery and css url with these

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: they way they recommend to embed is better, without specifying the protocol as it will inherit the visited one: src="//ajax.googleapis.com/...."

Comment: @bluehipy ohh yes that would be great idea either :) thnx

Comment: @userash please try idea of **@bluehipy** as well that would be great check is anything wrong with that i'm not sure about dis so

Answer (score 0):

You have listen for document ready twice, other then that it should work just fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#openwindow').each(function() {
                var $link = $(this);
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .load($link.attr('href'))
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: $link.attr('title'),
                        width: 500,
                        height: 300
                    });

                $link.click(function() {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');

                    return false;
                });
            });


            $('#wrapper').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Basic Dialog'
            });
            $('#opener').click(function() {
                var page = "https://www.google.com/finance/converter";

                var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        height: 250,
                        width: 350,
                        title: "Currency Converter"
                    });
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false;   
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="opener">Currency Converter</button>
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it because SSL is installed for the site?

Comment: Kind of, use same protocol for external scripts.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />